# How to Convert milliseconds to datetime in python or better alternative?

Tags: python, json, api

I have a JSON file that has an updated section and it updates in epoch milliseconds.
Currently, I have this code:

```
response = json.loads(response)
   for key, value in response.items():
      if key == "updated":
      print(value)
      ms = (value)
      print datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and this works. (Here `ms` is obviously `Integer` or `Float`)

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000.0)`

From documentation [Documentation datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

> class `datetime.time`:  An idealized time, independent of any  particular
>   day, assuming that every day has exactly 24*60*60 seconds.  (There is
>   no notion of “leap seconds” here.) Attributes: hour, minute,  second,
>   microsecond, and tzinfo.

Comment: ```File "discordbot.py", line 115
    print datetime.fromtimestamp(ms/1000
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
i get this error from my bot

Comment: this is how the json is stored, i'm trying to convert the last part
`{"cases":531804,"deaths":24073,"recovered":123942,"updated":1585274068595}`

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code to this, using datatime.fromtimestamp and dividing by 1000 puts it into seconds for it to ready

```
response = json.loads(response)
for key, value in response.items():
    if key == "updated":
       print(value)
       print(datetime.fromtimestamp (int (value / 1000)))
       activity = discord.Game("Updated Last " + str(datetime.fromtimestamp (int (value / 1000))))
       await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)
       await asyncio.sleep(10)
       bot.loop.create_task(on_ready())
```